# Org-mode capture and Evil - go into insert mode automatically

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evil-mode

I'm using org-mode capture to create small notes and todos. I'm also using evil-mode.

What I'd love to do is to automatically go into insert-mode when I go into a capture. I've tried adding a hook to org-capture-mode-hook and running (evil-insert) in the hook, but that doesn't work. Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks!

Simon

Answer (score 10):

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'org-capture-mode 'insert)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this solution did not work for me. I've tried to find out why, but have no idea.

Comment: According to [this bug](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/1115#issuecomment-450480141), `evil-set-initial-state` works only for major modes while `org-capture-mode` is a minor mode.